# d3 nesting on several keys with a loop

Tags: javascript, csv, svg, nested, d3.js

I am using d3.nest() in order to make a hierarchical object from a CSV file.

Could you please help me understand why the following code does not work.
I didn't manage to use the nesting function within a loop, as described below.

I have the following CSV file, taken from the examples on d3 website:

```
"type1","type2","type3","type4","type5","size"
"flare","analytics","cluster","AgglomerativeCluster","","3938"
"flare","analytics","cluster","CommunityStructure","","3812"
"flare","analytics","cluster","MergeEdge","","743"
"flare","analytics","graph","BetweennessCentrality","","3534"
"flare","analytics","graph","LinkDistance","","5731"
```

This basic nesting works:

```
data = data.entries(csv)
        .key(function(d) {return d.type1; })
        .key(function(d) {return d.type2; })
        .key(function(d) {return d.type3; })
        .entries(csv);
```

I want to use an array of values to specify my keys in order to modify them dynamically.

This works:

```
    var data = d3.nest();
    var nesting = ["type1","type2","type3"];
    data = data.key(function(d) {return d[nesting[0]]; });
    data = data.key(function(d) {return d[nesting[1]]; });
    data = data.key(function(d) {return d[nesting[2]]; });
    data = data.entries(csv);
```

But it does not work with a loop...

```
    var data = d3.nest();
    for(var i=0;i<nesting.length;i++)
    {
        data = data.key(function(d) {return d[nesting[i]]; });
    }
    data = data.entries(csv);
```

I can't understand why the loop version is not working... Maybe I miss something about the d3.nest() capabilities...

Also, I would like to know if there is a way to "skip" a nesting level if there is nothing filled at this level (ie: the "type5" level on all the lines from the extract above). How could I do that?

Thanks a lot for reading!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This isn't a problem with the `.nest()` operator, it's a problem with JavaScript closures. Any time you have this pattern:

```
for (var x=0; x < y; x++) {
    something.attachCallback(function() {
        // now do something with x
    });
}
```

You are going to have problems with the closure. The inner anonymous function you're defining doesn't include a copy of the value of `x`, it includes a *reference* to the outer variable `x`, which will update when the outer variable updates. So by the end of your loop, the value of `x` in *every* one of your callback functions will be the final value of `x` in the loop (in the code above, `y`; in your code, `nesting.length`).

The D3 `.nest()` operator uses its `.key()` arguments as callbacks - they aren't executed until you call `.map()` or `.entries()`. So the problem above applies.

There are various ways to fix this; I tend to use `.forEach()` instead of a `for` loop. This doesn't work in older browsers, but neither will most of D3, so you're probably safe:

```
var data = d3.nest();
nesting.forEach(function(key) {
    data.key(function(d) {return d[key]; })
});
```

Another option is to use a separate function for callback definition. Passing the iterator variable to another function will "fix" its value, as the callback now has a reference to the argument of the creator function, not to the original `x` variable:

```
var data = d3.nest();

function addKey(index) {
    data.key(function(d) { return d[nesting[index]]; })
}

for(var i=0;i<nesting.length;i++) {
    addKey(i);
}
```

There are a few other approaches as well, but in my opinion `forEach` is the most elegant.

Comment: @nrabinowitz shouldn't the leaf node be `key: something, values: number` instead, when following your code my leaf node (node at the end) has `key: something, values: []` ! It has an Array instead of the numeric value! Any ideas how I can get `values` to be the number?

Comment: what if i need to identify level based on group by ? suppose I have two group by as key than how should i know that this level is based on this values ? somehow i can add the attr that i use to group-by with key attr like attkey etc ?

Comment: @AmitRana - sounds like that might be something to post as a separate question.

Comment: @nrabinowitz here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723061/add-attribute-with-nested-entries-in-d3-js

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game, but this is a response to comment #2 above by @Ciwan.  I don't have enough "reputation" to comment, so I have to answer here:

The result of `d3.nest()` is correctly:

```
{ key: something, values: [all,the,items,that,are,grouped,by,the,key] }
```

If you'd rather have a count of those items, you can use d3.nest()'s rollup, like so:

```
var data = d3.nest().rollup(function(leaves) { return leaves.length; })
```

[Phoebe Bright's bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) is the canonical place to learn about d3.nest()