# D3.js: use d3.nest() adding keys dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am using `d3.nest()` to convert flat JSON files into hierarchical trees. This works just fine if you know in advance the levels that found in your data: `d3.nest()` creates a nesting-level for each key function you pass it.

However, I would like to know if there is an elegant way to dynamically pass key functions. This might be an elementary question, but my Javascript skills are also elementary.

This is a static example working with key names stored in an array:

```
var levels = ['first', 'second', 'third']

var root = {
    "key":"root", 
    "values": 
        d3.nest()
            .key(function(d){ return d[levels[0]] })
            .key(function(d){ return d[levels[1]] })
            .key(function(d){ return d[levels[2]] })
            .entries(data)
}
```

My solution now is an if-else loop that pseudo-dynamically creates different nestings:

```
// build the nested tree pseudo-dynamically
if (levels.length === 1) {
    var nest = d3.nest()
           .key(function(d){return d[levels[0]]})
           .entries(data);
} else if (levels.length === 2) {
    var nest = d3.nest()
           .key(function(d){return d[levels[0]]})
           .key(function(d){return d[levels[1]]})
           .entries(data);
} else if (levels.length === 3) {
    var nest = d3.nest()
           .key(function(d){return d[levels[0]]})
           .key(function(d){return d[levels[1]]})
           .key(function(d){return d[levels[2]]})
           .entries(data);
}
[...]
```

Is there an elegant way to dynamically pass keys to `d3.nest()`?  What I would like is something in principle like the following example (which DOES NOT WORK):

```
var root = {
    "key":"root", 
    "values": 
        d3.nest()
            for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
                .key(function(d){return d[levels[i]]})
            }
            .entries(data)
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It sounds like nesting isn't the right thing here. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913689/complex-d3-nest-manipulation) may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not as easy as you hypothetical elegant code, but you can certainly simplify it compared to your if-else method.

A first instinct is to do something like this:

```
var levels = ['first', 'second', 'third']

var nest = d3.nest();
for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
    nest = nest.key(function(d){return d[levels[i]]});
    //create a new nesting function that has one more key function added
    //and save it in the variable
}

var root = {
      "key":"root", 
      "values": nest.entries(data) //compute the nest
    }
```

**However**, this doesn't work because your nesting function won't be *used* until after you create all your nesting functions, so by the time the nest is actually run your `i` variable equals 3 and `levels[i]` returns undefined, and therefore `d[levels[i]]` returns undefined.  [Example here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/brVLH/).

You need to create a separate function enclosure so that the correct value from `levels` is locked in:

```
function createNestingFunction(propertyName){
  return function(d){ 
            return d[propertyName];
         };
}

var levels = ['first', 'second', 'third']

var nest = d3.nest();
for (var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
    nest = nest.key( createNestingFunction(levels[i]) );
    //create a new nesting function that has one more key function added
    //and save it in the variable

    //the function `createNestingFunction` is called *immediately*
    //with a parameter based on the current value of `i`
    //the returned function will always use that parameter,
    //regardless of how many times createNestingFunction is called
}

var root = {
      "key":"root", 
      "values": nest.entries(data) //compute the nest
    }
```

The working version of the example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/brVLH/1/

Comment: Thanks for such a good answer! That works very well and it is quite elegant actually!

Comment: what if i need to identify level based on group by ?
suppose I have two group by as key than how should i know that this level is based on this values ? somehow i can add the attr that i use to group-by with key attr like attkey etc ?

Comment: @AmitRana I'm not quite sure what you mean.  Maybe start a new question so that you can explain it more completely (with simple examples) and others can try to help?

Comment: @AmeliaBR, thank you, very useful. I've preferred to use forEach instead of the for loop, so you don't need the separate function: `levels.forEach(function (k) { nest = nest.key(function (d) { return d[k] });  });`

Answer (score 1):

Found another possible solution after posting the question. It uses forEach and it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414837/d3-nesting-on-several-keys-with-a-loop).

Comment: no adding multiple key is not problem ... What i wanted When i add multiple keys it group them based on that keys ...for each level I just want is which level is group by on which key ...

Comment: I seriously do not understand your comment, @Amit

Comment: Follow last example here 
                
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723061/add-attribute-with-nested-entries-in-d3-js

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution, following AmeliaBR one:

```
let levels = ['first', 'second', 'third']
// create the nest
let nest = d3.nest()
// for each value in 'levels' array
// add the key() function
levels.forEach(function(level){
  // re-assign to the nest key
  nest = nest.key(d => d[level])
});
// compute the nest
nest = nest.entries(data)
// add the root
let root = {
  "key":"root", 
  "values": nest
}
```